# How to solve error message "data.frame" are not all TRUE"

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using rTRIM to look at the population trends of hibernating bats. My dataset includes four columns (year, site, count, habitat) as this is apparently what you need for the analysis. Under "year" I obviously have numerous years between 2004 and 2020, under "site" I have site names, "count" I have the count number of individual bats and under "habitat" I have numbers 1 - 4 which represent the size of the site.

I enter the code:

```r
GHS <- trim(count ~ site + year + habitat, data=AllSites2, model=2, changepoints="all",
            serialcor=TRUE, overdisp=TRUE)
```

but I get the error message:

> Error in trim_workhorse(count, site, year, month, weights, covars, model,  :
> class(covars) == "data.frame" are not all TRUE

Can anyone help as I'm really stuck?!

Comment: I'd guess what triggers the bug is that `AllSites2` is a tibble.  Try using `as.data.frame(AllSites2)` in its place.

Answer (score 0):

That package has a bug in it.  It tests the `covars` argument (which you didn't use) with the test

```
stopifnot(class(covars) == "data.frame")
```

That's almost never a good test to use:  normally you should use

```
stopifnot(inherits(covars, "data.frame"))
```

I don't know what you can do about this.  You didn't call the `trim_workhorse` function directly.  I'd contact the package maintainer to ask for help:  `maintainer(rtrim)` (or `maintainer(rTRIM)` if that wasn't a typo) should get it for you.

I'd guess the issue is that `AllSites2` is a tibble or data table instead of a plain dataframe.  Try

```
GHS <- trim(count ~ site + year + habitat, data=as.data.frame(AllSites2), model=2, changepoints="all",
        serialcor=TRUE, overdisp=TRUE)
```